# nanoGallery2 - How to change Thumbnail icon

Tags: fonts, font-awesome, nanogallery

i'm using a nanoGallery2 and I did like to customize a thumbnail icon, on the documentation theres:

> All icons used in the gallery can be customized. By default, an icon
>   font is used. Example: replace the default album icon with a red one
>   from Font Awesome:

```
 icons.thumbnailAlbum: '<i style="color:#e00;" class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>'
```

But im trying to use the comment icon, like this:

```
icons: { thumbnailCustomTool1 : '<i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>'}
```

or

```
icons: { thumbnailCustomTool1 : '<i class="fa fa-comment"></i>'}
```

or

```
icons: { thumbnailCustomTool1 : '<i class="icon-comment"></i>'}
```

or

```
icons: { thumbnailCustomTool1 : '<i class="nGY2Icon icon-comment"></i>'}
```

and does not work :(

but some icons works well.. like..

```
icons: { thumbnailCustomTool1 : '<i class="nGY2Icon icon-star"></i>'}
```

What is the right way to change icons?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nanogallery2 is using a custom font, based on some icons from font awesome.

To use icons from another icon font, did you include the corresponding font in your HTML page?

For font awesome:
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />`

Here's a full working sample on CodePen: https://codepen.io/Kris-B/pen/EWmqdd

Comment: Thank you very much @Kris_B